# How to add numbers under that encoding?

Tags: haskell

As an fun experiment, I was looking for a binary representation of natural numbers with the simplest implementation of `log2`. This is the encoding I came up with:

```
data N = A N | B N | E
```

Where:

```
1       E
2       (A E)
3       (B E)
4       (A (A E))
5       (A (B E))
6       (B (A E))
7       (B (B E))
8       (A (A (A E)))
9       (A (A (B E)))
10      (A (B (A E)))
11      (A (B (B E)))
12      (B (A (A E)))
13      (B (A (B E)))
14      (B (B (A E)))
15      (B (B (B E)))
16      (A (A (A (A E))))
```

That makes `log2` as trivial as possible: you just count the number of `A` and `B`s! On that encoding, the usual "full adder" algorithm doesn't work anymore. Is there any simple algorithm that sums two numbers of N?

Comment: Reverse the encoding. Currently the outermost constructor is the most significant bit, with E meaning "no more bits". If you make the outermost constructor the least significant bit, the log2 implementation doesn't change, but the full adder algorithm becomes doable again, because as you step into two numbers, the bits mean the same thing.

Comment: @SebastianRedl yes, I just thought about that! Interesting. That might make a full adder feasible indeed. Let me think about it now!

Comment: @JohnColeman it looked obscure, indeed, but with his idea, now it is easy to find the encoded number. Something like that: `foldN (\ n r -> n (r*2)) (\ n r -> n (r*2+1)) (r -> r) n 1`.

Comment: Also, before I go: any intuitive reason this encoding seems to exclude 0?

Comment: @JohnColeman I'm not sure what you mean. I said that, by counting the number of `A`s and `B`s, you get `log2(N)`. So, for 8, there are 3 `A`s - i.e., `log2(8) == 3`.

Comment: I see -- I took "log2" as the name of your encoding.

Comment: @Viclib On intuition: treat `A` as 0 and `B` as 1 in the usual binary representation of numbers. Then in your encoding there is an implicit 1 that you do not include; but since you don't include it, *every* number has a 1 in its most significant digit, hence you cannot represent 0.

Comment: I think using `E` as `0` instead of `1` is a better solution here, since that will actually make this representation closed w.r.t. `log2` (i.e. you can represent result of `log2` as `N`). Implementation is marginally more complicated (i.e. number of `A`s and `B`s minus one), but it boils down to 2 additional pattern matches. Besides, adding `0` will make your `N` a commutative semiring under normal addition and multiplication.